# two foreign keys in one model sqlalchemy duplicate

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There are other answers on stacked overflow and I followed them. Its been 3 days with this problem and i have searched all answers before and i feel that even if  its repeat question i should be afraid to ask if I cant get it to work after much researching.

the desired result is foreign keys in one model using sqlalchemy

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class OrderHistory(db.Model):    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    user = db.relationship(User, foreign_keys=[user_id], backref='user')
    seller = db.relationship(User, foreign_keys=[seller_id], backref='seller')
```

But i keep getting this error

```
AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.order_history - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

What am i dong wrong?

Comment: what is your  sqlalchemy version?

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy V 0.10 What i do is from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

Comment: Don't you need a primary key column for `OrderHistory`?

Comment: I think this version problem. This code will run below sqlalchemy>=0.9

Comment: i do need a primary key column order history but i left it just to have less code

Comment: Did you try removing the `backref` arguments? They don't really make sense - as they would try to create relationships "user" and "seller" again on the `User` class. Plus - the error message doesn't fit your code sample. The error quotes a "User.order_history" relationship that doesn't exist in your code snippet...

Comment: Tried removing the backref still same problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting seller as a secondary table like  user = db.relationship(User, viewonly=True, secondary='seller', backref='user')

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

to

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
```

Answer (score -2):

Checkout [this example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship) on the documentation. Probably you are using a sqlalchemy version <= 0.8 and that's why your code your code won't work.